# multiple images loading over each other

Tags: jquery, css

i am facing a very strange problem . i am using multiple images inside a div to load on the same position. the problem is each and every image is loading on top of each other while loading . the css position is set to`absolute` and i just want that the first image loads up the rest of the image loads beneath the first image not over it . and rest the slider would handle . can anyone help me with this ?

my structure is as follows for the images

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item item-1 active" style="display: block;">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="./eg/eg-101.jpg" alt="Breakers">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-1 active" style="display: block;">
        <div class="image">
             <img src="./eg/eg-102.jpg" alt="Breakers">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, things lower in the DOM have a higher z-index and will appear on top. Setting a z-index for the element you want on top would put it above the rest of the elements. Setting a z-index on all of the elements would allow you to 'stack' them in any order you would like.

Comment: thanks for the reply @Matthew but how can i just target the first image to be the highest on z-index as all these images are being added by script dynamically ?

Comment: Alter the dynamic script to add the z-index property or a class you can use to apply it. It's hard to say without knowing what you are doing to generate the HTML in the first place.

Comment: but how to target the very first class "item" for higher z-index?

Comment: .item:first-child img { z-index: 100; }

Comment: @Wk_of_Angmar thanks a lot any way we can do this via jquery?

Comment: It's not a good idea to mix CSS and JavaScript together if it can be avoided. That CSS I wrote will always select the first .item element of its parent, then it will select the img and apply the CSS. This means that the first image will always be on top.

Note that if you want to be able to change the z-index order, then I recommend you make a new class called "top", apply the z-index property to that class using CSS, then use JavaScript/jQuery to add that class to the first image when the images are being inserted. Then you can add/remove the class to other image elements when necessary.

Comment: thank you for such good explanation but if still there is a possible way with jquery you could help me out with it would be best for me